# NSLayoutConstraint in a Loop FOR

Tags: ios, objective-c, for-loop, uilabel, constraints

I'm trying to create `UILabel` through a `for` loop that gets its `NSInteger` from an `NSArray`. The cycle works properly but I can not see all the vertices one below the other. I'm definitely wrong something with constraint. Can you help me?

Based on this code I posted how can I fix the `NSLayoutConstraint` problem within a `for` loop?

```
NSInteger max = [[_yValueArray valueForKeyPath:@"@max.self"] integerValue];
NSInteger min = [[_yValueArray valueForKeyPath:@"@min.self"] integerValue];

for (NSInteger value = max; value >= min; value -=1) {
    UILabel *valueLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    valueLabel.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    valueLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    valueLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    valueLabel.font = [UIFont defaultAppFontWithSize:10];
    valueLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    valueLabel.text = [self yValueString:value];
    valueLabel.tag = value;

    [yAxisView addSubview:valueLabel];

    [yAxisView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:valueLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:valueLine attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft multiplier:1 constant:-2]];

    NSLayoutConstraint *topConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:valueLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:yAxisView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1 constant:0];
    [yAxisView addConstraint:topConstraint];

    NSLayoutConstraint *height = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:valueLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:valueLine attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:1 constant:10];
     [yAxisView addConstraint: height];

    // topConstraint.constant += height.constant;        

}
```

---

---

What I'm trying to get is a bar graph like this ... At this time I wanted to get the result of the Y axis you see in the image ...[image]

Comment: @Rob I'm trying to create a bar graph. At this time I'm building the Y axis that contains the reference values from 18 to 30 ... in the cycle for i want to get all the numbers from 18 to 30 and put them in the labels and these they must be placed vertically. From the top begins 30, then 29, then, 28 etc ... until reaching 18

Comment: I need these labels because when I create the X axis with a UIView representing the graph bar I can make a report based on the text of the label and the other value inserted in the bar graph

Comment: i'm edited my post

Comment: I had already created everything with two collectionView and I was almost able to complete my project ... I had the MAX value to vertically fill a cell (chart bar) but I have problems with the MIN value ... if I succeeded find help for this I would have solved all my problems :( but i could not find anyone who would help me solve this little problem with the MIN value

Comment: the last posts you entered have been deleted why??

Comment: Because I was answering a different question, how to do the bars, themselves. I clearly misunderstood your question. Frankly, I'm still not 100% clear what the question is. Is it that the labels are not being placed in the right place vertically? And you talk about two collection views? Is this chart generated by some collection view? You show us what you want the chart to look like, but not what it currently looks like. Maybe that would help clarify the problem.

Comment: @Rob No no ... this was right ... I had added other experiences I had but I had to stop everything because I could not get what I was talking about. Now I was trying again with a simple uiview and not with uicollectionView ... even if I think UICollectionView is better

Comment: We can move two minutes in chat, maybe we can fix it better I'll see some pictures and some pieces of code to better understand ... if you do not mind

Comment: FWIW, I think collection view just makes this a lot more complicated. If you're trying to simplify this, I'd consider one of the many charting libraries out there (e.g. CorePlot or others; just google for "iOS chart library").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm gathering that the question is labeling the left axis vertically.

If your goal is to add labels to the left edge, you can set the `centerY` constraint as a multiple of the `centerY` of its superview. The only trick is that it doesn't like a `0` for the multiplier for `centerY`, so for that top one, I'd just set the `centerY` to be equal to the top of its superview. Thus:

```
NSInteger max = 10;

for (NSInteger i = 0; i <= max; i++) {
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)i];
    [self.chartDataView addSubview:label];

    CGFloat multiplier = (CGFloat)(max - i) * 2.0 / (CGFloat)max;

    [self.chartDataView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:label attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.chartDataView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft multiplier:1 constant:-5]];

    if (multiplier == 0) {
        [self.chartDataView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:label attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.chartDataView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1 constant:0]];
    } else {
        [self.chartDataView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:label attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.chartDataView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY multiplier:multiplier constant:0]];
    }
}
```

Yields:

[image]

Clearly, I'm not drawing any chart, but this shows how, given a chart graph area, you can use the multiplier to dictate where the labels go.